# How to save a list to shared preferences

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I want to save a list to shared preferences, but it doesn't work... The goal is to add data to the variable and save it.

This is the variable I want to save:

```
    var savedData = [
      {'date': 0, 'testNumber': 0},
    ];
```

And this is the code I tried for saving and receiving the variable:

```
 Future<void> saveDataTest() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setStringList(
        'dataTest', savedData.map((i) => i.toString()).toList());
  }
    
 Future<String> getDataStringTest() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    savedData =
     prefs.getStringList('dataTest').map((i) => int.parse(i)).toList();
    setState(() {});
  }
```

This is the error I get:

```
A value of type 'List<int>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<Map<String, int>>'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'List<Map<String, int>>'.
```

Comment: You didn't store a list of `int`. You stored a list of `Map<String, int>`. So `(i) => int.parse(i)` is going to be a problem.

Comment: Ok thanks! And what is the solution for this problem?

Comment: I'm not prepared to run the code to know for certain. You can try `(i) => Map<String, int>.from(i)`

Comment: When I try your code I get this error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'

Comment: What type of variable is `savedData`?

Comment: savedData is a var and all data I put inside are int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `jsonEncode` and `jsonDecode` from `import 'dart:convert';`

Like so:

```
 Future<void> saveDataTest() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setString("dataTest ", jsonEncode(savedData));
  }
    
 Future<String> getDataStringTest() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    savedData = List.from(jsonDecode(prefs.getString("dataTest")));
    setState(() {});
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I try this I get this error: _TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String')

Comment: It is when I try to get  the data

Comment: I've updated my answer, try it with that.

Comment: Wipe the storage for the app to clear the preferences or programmatically remove the preference. Then run this code and see if it works.

Comment: Now I get this error: Exception has occurred.
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: length)

Answer (score 2):

As you are using in your list a Map object with primitive types, you can use `jsonEncode` and convert to a String that can be saved in sharedPreferences and use `jsonDecoder` when want to revert.

like this:

```
String toBeSaved = jsonEncode(savedData);
prefs.setString('dataTest', toBeSaved);
```